# Inputting a function which returns a list into calc() in R

Tags: r, plot, raster, r-raster

I create a logistic function, "fun", that calculates several parameters, ie: SOS, EOS, LOS, SPUDOY, and P_Tamplitude, using a .envi raster file. Ultimately, I would like to generate separate plots for each parameter.

I use calc() to perform "fun" on Data_value. It works when "fun" returns only one variable. However, calc() fails when "fun" returns all five parameters aforementioned - which is a list.

```
new <- stack("1982_test.envi")
new[new<=-1000]<-0
Data_value<-new/10000
DOY<-(1:nlayers(new)*15)

fun<- function(x) { if (all(is.na(x[1]))) { return (NA) } else { 
fitForThisData  <-nls(x~ a+((b/(1+ exp(-c*(DOY-e))))- (g/(1+ exp(-d*(DOY-
f))))), alg="port",start=list(a=0.1,b=1,g=1,c=0.04,d=0.04,e=112,f=218),
lower=list(a=0,b=0.3,g=0.3,c=-1,d=-1,e=20,f=100),
upper=list(a=0.4,b=2,g=2,c=1,d=1,e=230,f=365),
control=nls.control(maxiter=2000, tol = 1e-15, minFactor = 1/1024, 
warnOnly=TRUE))
SOS<-(coef(fitForThisData)[6] -(4.562/(2*coef(fitForThisData)[4])))
EOS<-(coef(fitForThisData)[7] -(4.562/(2*coef(fitForThisData)[5])))
LOS<-(EOS-SOS)
SPUDOY<-(1.317*((-1/coef(fitForThisData)[4])+ coef(fitForThisData)[6]))
P_TAmplitude<-(SPUDOY-SOS)
return (c(SOS,EOS,LOS,SPUDOY,P_TAmplitude))
}
}

equation<-calc(Data_value,fun)
```

After running the command above, it says there is an error.
    Error in setValues(out, x) : 
    values must be numeric, integer, logical or factor

```
plot(equation)
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: FWIW, `fun` doesn't return a list, but a vector. Have you considered `forceapply=TRUE` argument from `?calc`?

Comment: I think vector is a list. It is just a different lingo in R. (http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/vector).

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I just picked up R. Forgive me if I am wrong, but I think vector is a list. It is just a different lingo in R. (http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/vector). 
 I tried using forceapply=TRUE in calc(), I got the same error as well. I'm also thinking of using sapply, but I don't think it works for raster data. I am also thinking maybe I can return the values in matrix instead of a list. I'd like to generate 5 layers of data (SOS, EOS, LOS, SPUDOY and P_TAmplitude) and perform calc(). I think R doesn't understand how the data should be stored. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code with some sample data and it actually works unless I don't insert NA values. 
It looks like there is an issue with the number of NA values you return. 
The length in case that an NA occurs needs to be same as when no NA occurs. In your case it's however 1 and 5.

Try to change the following line:

```
return(NA)
```

to

```
return(rep(NA,5))
```

Comment: It is showing me five plots now with the little tweak you suggested! Thank you very much! @maRtin

Comment: You are welcome! I would appreciate an upvote if you found my answer helpful. @Candice

Comment: @maRtin I'd say Martin the Genius. great answer.